# Writing a function that lemmatizes all words in a sentence by considering their POS tags

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I am trying to use wordnet lemmatizer in python and i have noticed that the default pos tag is NOUN and that it does not output the correct lemma for a verb, unless the pos tag is explicitly specified as VERB.

How can i create a function

```
proper_lemmatize_sentence(raw1, True)
```

so that if its "True" it gives the lemma according to its pos tag or else if its "False" it gives the default lemma for pos=n

i have tried the following

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
raw1 = 'Corpus linguistics proposes that reliable language analysis is more feasible with corpora collected in the field, in their natural contexts, and with minimal experimental-interference.'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw1)
wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized_tokens = [wnl.lemmatize(tk) for tk in tokens]
print(lemmatized_tokens)
```

Comment: I don't understand; it sounds like the wordnet lemmatizer works like you want it to. Or do you have the pos tags you want stored somewhere?

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb from https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L66